# attribute not found payfort SDK

Tags: java, android, payfort

**build.gradle(module:app)**

```
    implementation 'com.shazam.fork:fork:3.7.0'
    implementation project(path: ':gson-2.6.2')
    implementation project(path: ':fort_android_sdk_dependancies_v4')
    implementation project(path: ':fonticon-0.1.8-sources')
    implementation project(path: ':bcprov-jdk16-1.46')
    implementation project(path: ':FORTSDKv1.5')
```

can't find payfort SDK resources

### please check these images

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22664709/61167871-a4310a00-a4f9-11e9-841e-497c584d4e19.PNG

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22664709/61167872-a4c9a080-a4f9-11e9-9480-2ec484cdd72b.PNG

Comment: Plz use dependencies as suggested by payFort sdk team in their "AndroidStudio_gradle.txt" file